# How to convert Long type in DateTime with joda in scala?

Tags: scala

How can I convert Long type in DateTime with joda in scala?

```
val a = 1234526278L

val b: DateTime = 1234526278L.DateTime
```

Answer (score 3):

Creation of date time is trivial (assuming given long represents "milliseconds from epoch"):

```
val b = new DateTime(a)
```

But i assume author wanted to know how to obtain desired syntax, this can be achived with the following code:

```
class LongExtension(private val l: Long) extends AnyVal {
  def toDateTime = new DateTime(l)
}

implicit def toExtension(l: Long) = new LongExtension(l)
```

Now if the implicit conversion is available in scope, following syntaxt can be used:

```
val c = a.toDateTime
```

Comment: If you are going to deal with implicits, just do `implicit def dt(l: Long) = new DateTime(l); val c: DateTime = 12345l`

Answer (score 2):

```
scala> import org.joda.time.DateTime
import org.joda.time.DateTime
scala> val b = new DateTime(a)
b: org.joda.time.DateTime = 1970-01-15T12:25:26.278+05:30
```